# Semantic ui submit multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui for my ui and form validation, i am trying trigger login api after validation is done (i replaced that with console). When i try to submit, it submits three times.

```js
$('.ui.form')
  .form({
    fields: {
      username : ['minLength[4]', 'empty'],
      password : ['minLength[6]', 'empty'],
    },
        onSuccess : function() 
    {
      // Login api process here
      console.log("weed");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.9/semantic.min.css">

 <div class="ui grid">
 
 <div class="five wide column" style="margin: 0px auto; margin-top: 5vh;">

  <div class="ui form segment error">

  <h3 class="ui centered header">Please Login</h3>

  <div class="ui form">

    <div class="field">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input name="username" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input name="password" type="password">
    </div>

        <button class="primary submit ui button">Login</button>

  </div>

  <div class="ui error message"></div>

  </div>

  <div style="display: none;" class="ui segment">

    <p></p>
    <div class="ui active dimmer">
      <div class="ui loader"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

 </div>

 </div>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have multiple `.ui.form` classes in your HTML markup. I would recommend on the second instance adding a new class or ID like so:

```
<div class="ui form theForm">
```

Then in your JS:

```
$('.theForm').form({
  fields: {
    username: ['minLength[4]', 'empty'],
    password: ['minLength[6]', 'empty'],
  },
  onSuccess: function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // Login api process here
    console.log("weed");
  }
});
```

JSFiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/am63qe8h/

Comment: Or just removing the `.form` from one of the `div`s, also `e.stopImmediatePropagation` doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You're right, I should have removed e.stopImmediatePropagation as that was my first attempt at not logging three success events.

Comment: I didn't chnge the js.. just the html and it worked fine

Comment: This solution solved my problem. Please use $('.ui.form') in the console to check how many elements it can find. If more than one, you should add your custom form class for each form, such as <div class="ui form from-do-xxx">